# scala for with () vs {} parenthesis vs curly braces

Tags: scala, for-loop

I have seen for loops, comprehensions with both parenthesis () and curly braces {} they look awfully similar. I always thought they were the same, until I wrote this code:

Version 1:

```
def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos = {
    val positions =
      for {
        row_index <- 0 to levelVector.length - 1
        col_index <- 0 to levelVector(row_index).length - 1
        if (levelVector(row_index)(col_index) == c)
      } yield Pos(row_index, col_index)
    if (positions.length == 1) positions.head
    else throw new Exception(s"expected to find 1 match, but found ${positions.length} matches instead")
  }
```

Version 2:

```
def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos = {
    val positions =
      for (
        row_index <- 0 to levelVector.length - 1;
        col_index <- 0 to levelVector(row_index).length - 1;
        if (levelVector(row_index)(col_index) == c)
      ) yield Pos(row_index, col_index)
    if (positions.length == 1) positions.head
    else throw new Exception(s"expected to find 1 match, but found ${positions.length} matches instead")
  }
```

Version 1 has curly braces, while Version 2 has parenthesis. But I also noticed Version 2 didn't compile without the use of semi colons at the end of the arrow lines. Why is this?! Are these two fors even the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope they are not the same.

`{}` means to group lines of code considering the `next line` (\n)

`()` means grouping as well but doesn't consider *next line* (\n) so even if you have `\n` in the middle all of the codes inside `()` the lines of code are considered as one line.

Answer (score 3):

`for` loop definition in [scala spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops)

> Expr1          ::=  ‘for’ (‘(’ Enumerators ‘)’ | ‘{’ Enumerators ‘}’)
>                          {nl} [‘yield’] Expr
>
> Enumerators    ::=  Generator {semi Generator}
>
> Generator      ::=  Pattern1 ‘<-’ Expr {[semi] Guard | semi Pattern1 ‘=’ Expr}
>
> Guard          ::=  ‘if’ PostfixExpr

So they are the same except of newline acceptance.

For the case of curly braces in scala [lexical syntax](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/spec/01-lexical-syntax.md) you can find:

> Multiple newline tokens are accepted in the following places (note that a semicolon in place of the newline would be illegal in every one of these cases):
>
> - between the condition of a conditional expression or while loop and the next following expression,
> - between the enumerators of a for-comprehension and the next following expression, and
> - after the initial type keyword in a type definition or declaration.